# C++ convert JSON to XML

Tags: c++, pugixml

I am trying to find a way to convert JSON string to XML document. For this we have evaluated PICOJSON to parse JSON and Pugixml to generate the XML document.

I know this is way easy in .Net and JAVA.  My JSON is dynamic and based on the dynamic JSON I have to convert to XML.

I need some starting help on how to achieve this.  Below code is sample to Parse JSON

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/picojson.h";
#include "include/pugixml.hpp";
using namespace std;

int main() {
   
    const char* json =
        "{\"menu\": {"
        "\"id\": \"f\","
        "\"popup\": {"
        "  \"menuitem\": ["
        "    {\"v\": \"0\"},"
        "    {\"v\": \"1\"},"
        "    {\"v\": \"2\"}"
        "   ]"
        "  }"
        "}"
        "}";
    picojson::value v;
    std::string err;
    const char* json_end = picojson::parse(v, json, json + strlen(json), &err);
    
}
```

I think the initial approach would be to covert JSON String to JSON object(Not sure how to do that) and then recursively construct XML
Will the below code convert JSON string to Object ?

```
picojson::parse(v, json, json + strlen(json), &err);
    if (!err.empty()) {
        std::cerr << err << std::endl;
    }
```

Can someone guide me with initial code on how to do it, how to construct XML from JSON ?

Comment: Do you know your expectation from given json?

Comment: "Completely new to C++" is probably not a good combination with using advanced libraries for JSON and XML. And it kind-of shows with your use of `printf`. First learn the basics of C++, and learn away `printf` or other "C-isms" like that. Then break down the somplex task of converting JSON to XML into smaller sub-problems, continue breaking down each sub-problem into smaller and smaller parts until it's not possible any more. Then implement each little and now *simple* problem, one by one.

Comment: Unrelated advice: use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to make JSONs inside CPP sources somewhat readable: https://godbolt.org/z/Ez937rf39

Comment: The question here was more on the approach to solve it rather than asking complete code. Sometimes one will be in  a situation to be Technology Agnostic and have to work on business needs of the organization.  I can understand C++, sorry for the initial saying about completely new to C++.   If there is some approach I will definitely try to dig deeper more on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use RapidJSON instead, you can make a SAX parser based on [this example](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html) and map each JSON *read event* to an homologous XML *write operation*.

Hint: this probably means keeping a `pugi::xml_node currentNode` somewhere to keep track of the current node being worked on.

---

**Edit**
It seems POCO has [SAX-like handlers](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.JSON.Handler.html) after all, so you won't even need RapidJSON for this.
And if you want to minimize your dependencies, you can also use POCO.XML instead of pugixml.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading, I have to use PICOJSON and PugiXML

Comment: Oh ok. According to their doc there's something similar with PicoJson too: https://github.com/kazuho/picojson#reading-json-using-the-streaming-event-driven-interface